# How to build my HelloWorld Android application with Necessitas (qt port)?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qt-necessitas

I have ant 1.8.2. Latest version of Android SDK, NDK. Thats my build log.

```
Running build steps for project test2...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Вход в каталог `/home/andrew/work/qt/test2-build-android'
make: Цель `first' не требует выполнения команд.
make: Выход из каталога `/home/andrew/work/qt/test2-build-android'
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
Copy Qt app & libs to Android package ...
Stripping libraries, please wait
Creating package file ...
Package Creation: Running command '/home/andrew/eclipse/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant debug'
Buildfile: /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/build.xml

    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 10

    [setup] Project Target: Android 1.5
    [setup] API level: 3
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] 
    [setup] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
    [setup] 
    [setup] Importing rules file: tools/ant/main_rules.xml

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-set-debug-mode:

-compile-tested-if-test:

-pre-build:

-dirs:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/bin/classes

-aidl:
     [echo] Compiling aidl files into Java classes...

-renderscript:
     [echo] Compiling RenderScript files into Java classes and RenderScript bytecode...

-resource-src:
     [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...
     [aapt] /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'largeScreens' in package 'android'

     [aapt] /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'normalScreens' in package 'android'
     [aapt] /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'anyDensity' in package 'android'
     [aapt] /home/andrew/work/qt/test2/android/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'smallScreens' in package 'android'

BUILD FAILED
/home/andrew/eclipse/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:310: null returned: 1

Total time: 1 second
Packaging Error: Command '/home/andrew/eclipse/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant debug' failed.Exit code: 1
Error while building project test2 (target: Android)
When executing build step 'Packaging for Android'
```

Comment: For me, I had to set my JAVA_HOME system enviro var - thanks to this other question on StackOverflow for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453753/how-do-i-fix-android-packaging-error-for-necessitas-qt

Answer (score 1):

Sounds for me as if you did not select any target platform, respectively did not configure your SDK properly.

1.) The official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

2.) A movie by nokia where you can see how the guy configures [necessitas](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/28/necessitas/) on linux: