# How do I fix Android packaging error for Necessitas (Qt)?

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build my HelloWorld Android application with Necessitas (qt port)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422931/how-to-build-my-helloworld-android-application-with-necessitas-qt-port)

This is my first time posting here, so if this post seems like it should be in a different section feel free to let me know =).

I am trying to run a simple application for Android using Necessitas. The application does not have any functionality; all it does is display (or is supposed to display) a button on the screen. I am just doing this as a test to get a feel for Necessitas before I start any serious development. When I hit the ‘run’ button Necessitas begins to build my application, but then stops and displays the following error message:

> Packaging Error: Command
>   ‘C:\Users\Catalyst\necessitas/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant.bat clean
>   debug’ failed.Exit code: 1 Error while building project atest2
>   (target: Android) When executing build step ‘Packaging for Android’

A search on Google did not produce any instructions to help remedy my issue. I also posted this question in the Qt developer forum. It's been nearly a week since I posted there and no one answered. Please help me! I have a lot of great ideas for apps that I would like to start developing ASAP!

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. Problem is in java files. I can't remember what I have done exactly but download latest java and install it and then try. Meanwhile I'll try to see what I have done exactly.

O yea I remember you need to set enviroment variable to you java jdk. So go start\right- click my computer press enviromment variables and in system variables you'll see JAVA_HOME variable edit path to you jdk for example: c:\program file\java\jdk 1.7.0

And that worked for me.

Denonth

Comment: right, must set JAVA_HOME,  such as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25" in windows,  add env var in QTCreate Build environment is not work.

Comment: try to update to new android SDK...and restart all..maybe something went wrong with installation process..btw. which NDK do you have? Is ANT set properly in QT creator?

Answer (score 2):

i've had the same problem like you and i installed the winant over the winant version in my "necessitas" folder `C:\Users\krikit\necessitas\apache-ant-1.8.4\` . After a system restard it worked.

krikit

here you can find the [winant](http://code.google.com/p/winant/)