# Necessitas (Qt/Android NDK) qmake paths

Tags: android, qt4, qt-necessitas, precompiling

I am running openSUSE 12.2 64-bit trying to compile an app in Necessitas alpha 4.1.  It's a basic app and the code is likely not the issue.  Through the course of tracing the issue I made sure to have all dependencies and tools.jar, which can apparently cause similar errors.  When compiling I get:

```
Packaging Error: Command '/usr/bin/ant clean debug' failed.Exit code: 1
File not found:
```

No file is actually listed.  I copy/pasted this line from Projects->Build Steps->qmake:

```
/home/mark/Software/necessitas/Android/Qt/482/armeabi-v7a/bin/qmake /home/mark/Dev/qt/myProject/myProject.pro -r -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug
```

Then I pasted in a terminal window and the result is:

```
sh: /home/mark/necessitas/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

This is obviously incorrect as my path is ~/Software/necessitas not ~/necessitas.  I have checked through every tab of Tools->Options but see nowhere that references the incorrect folder.  Any clue where this is supposed to go?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact error last night. However I noticed that the Google documentation specifically said java-6-openjdk. So I installed the older JDK using synaptic and then ran:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I selected the version 6 and re-ran the process. Which completed successfully.

(To be fair I was using Qt 5.1 beta 1 and freshly downloaded NDK and SDK's, ant was 1.8.1 from the repositories)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I haven't been using Qt as much anymore, been doing mostly PHP or occasionally work in Eclipse.  I do have 1 project that won't be easy to port so I'll still need to get it going when I want to work on that project, but now I'm thinking this question is mostly obsoleted due to Qt's new release.  If I find a solution I'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to resolve your problem in the mean time ?

This has to do with the Java environment variables, more precisely with JAVA_HOME.
Did you install OpenJDK right before you tried to launch your app ?
I am not certain where OpenJDK installs in OpenSUSE, but on my ArchLinux the variable had to be set to :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
```

in order for QtCreator to compile the project properly.

In my case, I had Oracle's JDK installed, so right after installing OpenJDK, loging out and reloging updated my environment variables as wished.

There is also a similar post to yours:
[How to build my HelloWorld Android application with Necessitas (qt port)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422931/how-to-build-my-helloworld-android-application-with-necessitas-qt-port?lq=1)

And you'll find a good necessitas starter video here :
http://youtu.be/suPeZ7XC1xk

Comment: I still haven't figured this out.  I ended up using Eclipse for that project instead.  My .bash_profile is:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/jre/bin
openSUSE does some weird things with symlinks in Java.  I'll test 32-bit paths when I get a chance to look again, and I think the /jre directory is right, but I'll double-check that too.  Thanks

Comment: Here are the java paths I have on my Archlinux (64bits) desktop.
Obviously, my JAVA_HOME points to the whole openjdk jvm folder, not just the jre.
`printenv | grep java;
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk;
J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk;
J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre;`

Comment: I tried changing the build paths and with how long it's been I've forgotten exactly how to duplicate this, but it still doesn't compile.  I now have exit code 2 instead of 1.  Also my qmake somehow decided to use standard qmake path instead of necessitas qmake, so I symlinked my default mkspec directory to necessitas mkspec.  This put me back to /home/mark/necessitas/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory.  My problem stems from /necessitas being inside of ~/Software and not in the root of ~/

Comment: Well, you need a Qt Version pointing to Necessitas' qmake (no matter where it is). Check in Qt Creator's `Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions`, if have it configured correctly. If not, add a new one, pointing to **qmake** (`.../Necessitas/necessitas/Android/Qt/482/armeabi-v7a/bin/qmake`). Meanwhile, I use Qt Creator 2.7 RC which includes Android functionalities (but not the Necessitas builds, which must then be linked).